# Are all DUB cranks compatible?

Tags: crankset, sram

I have a dub crankset with arm length 175 (https://www.sram.com/en/truvativ/models/fc-styl-7k-b1)

I want to change the crank arm length to 167.5

There's no 167.5 crank arm for SRAM MTB line (I think SX/NX/GX/XX1/X01 are MTBs?)

I found `Red` and `Force` 167.5 arms which are also `DUB` (I think these `Red` and `Force` are for road?)

So can I mix the `Red` or `Force` crank arm ([https://www.amazon.com/SRAM-Force-AXS-Crank-Assembly/dp/B07WCRY3BY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WCRY3BY)) with my existing MTB crankset ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are set on 167.5mm instead of 165mm or 170mm? A 2.5mm difference is likely smaller than most people can notice. It seems likely that either of these common crank lengths would be OK for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Road cranks are not going to work on your MTB.

The crank arms include the crank axle - one of the arms is permanently attached to the axle. The axle length is important. Road bikes use narrower bottom bracket shells than MTBs and hence have shorter axles.

Comment: Thank you...! might require a new question but.. would https://www.lightningbikes.com/store/index.html#!/Lightning-MTB-cranks/p/112573936/category=30267618 this work for me? they have `osbb (specialized)` listed.. but don't say dub.. does that mean, I'll have to buy `osbb` bottom bracket as well to use the crankset?

Comment: Personally I would not touch a carbon crank from a manufacturer I have never heard of. What you should do at this point is learn a bit more about bottom bracket standards so you wont have to keep asking if certain cranks fit your bike. Start [here](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/the-complete-guide-to-bottom-bracket-standards/) and [here](https://wheelsmfg.com/bb-standards).

Comment: Also make sure you understand *chain-line*. That's the distance from the center line of the chainrings to the center line of the frame. Different drivetrain setups require different crank chain-lines. This is related to the width of the rear hub and how far outboard the cassette is positioned.

Comment: I tried reading that article about bottom bracket. just so overwhealming.. I guess i'll give it another try.. Thank you.

Comment: @eugene Reading the crank specifications, they don't say what axle diameter they use. DUB refers to the crank axle diameter (28.99mm). Now, I have heard of Lightning during my weight weenie days, and I know these cranks predate the introduction of DUB. So, if you decide to get them, assume you will need to change your BB.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Lightning web site says BB bearings are integrated/come with, so the frame interface is what matters. OP's Spclzd has threaded shell but we don't know what width, and the Lightning page does not list threaded shell widths